# IOBluetooth Rename JBL/UE Speaker

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth, rename, iobluetooth

I am currently building a massive Bluetooth control framework for Mac OS X in Objective C and I have included a rename method that can send a rename request (change advertised name) to compatible bluetooth devices.

For Example: Rename a JBL Speaker through the JBL Connect App or Rename a UE Speaker through the UE Boom app.

It would be awesome to learn how to do this.

For anyone who's not really sure but is smart with bluetooth, How do you think this would be accomplished? would it be in the SDP or in a service attribute or perhaps something in the Low Energy section? how would i do this.

Even if someone could get me the .ipa of the JBL Connect app that would be a massive help cause I could disassemble it and have a lil look inside see if theres anything i can learn.

Anyways thanks :D